# EXCEL VLOOKUP/MATCH/VARIABLE

Tags: excel-2010

Good Evening and thanks in advance for taking the time to read and help.

I have a 3 column excel file which I am trying to populate the 3rd column with a return value found next to the row its found in.

so for example I want to look at column MANAGERSFULLNAME for value 
Cheryl Rommelfanger and find the match in column FULLNAME. Once the match is found I want to populate MANAGERSX2FULLNAME but not with the value found in FULLNAME but with the value next to in column MANAGERSFULLNAME

So for this example we look in MANAGERSFULLNAME for Cheryl Rommelfanger and find the match in FULLNAME Cheryl Rommelfanger then populate MANAGERSX2FULLNAME with
William Dearth

FULLNAME    MANAGERSFULLNAME    MANAGERSX2FULLNAME
Dena Peters Cheryl Rommelfanger 
Kyle Marsh  Melissa Hall
Cheryl Rommelfanger William Dearth

ive tried a few things and can only get a count not the value next to it.

=MATCH($E2&$F2,INDEX($B2:B4000&$C2:C4000,),)

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E2,F2,$B$2:B$4000,$C$2:C$4000,0)),"",E2)

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(L2,$K$2:K$4000,0)),"",L20)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I apologize but I am having a bit of trouble understanding your columns, but the general idea is clear.

Your attempts are really close.  You want to use index(match) as opposed to match(index).  The link below describes how to do this.

[Index match formula](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/index-match-formula-excel/)

If I'm understanding you correctly it sounds like you're trying to find and list the bosses boss so-to-speak to display a hierarchy of sorts.  I'm using just columns A, B, and C (C being the managerx2fullname) this formula should work fine:

```
=index(B$2:B$4000,match(B2,A$2:A$4000,0))
```

You will of course need to change the columns to fit your needs.  Don't include a dollar sign in B2 because you want this to increment as you drag the formula down the column.  The link below shows a screen shot from my test.  In it we see that in row 2 John is Adams boss, who in turn is Joe's boss.  I think that's what you're shooting for here.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmrfh.png)